# Taking out all classes of a specific namespace

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces

Is there a way to get an object from a specific namespace? Perhaps with the `System.Reflections`? I want to get all objects from type `ITestType` in the namespace `Test.TestTypes` as Objects so that I have a list of instances of `TestType1, TestType2, TestType3` and so on. Can Someone help me? I don't know where to search for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all types in a namespace via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can find all the *types* within an assembly, and find all of those types which match the given namespace (this is really easy with LINQ) - but if you don't have a specific assembly to look through, you need to examine *all* of the possible ones.

However, if you're looking for a way of finding all the live *objects*, that's a different matter - and you can't do it without using the profiler API, as far as I'm aware. (Even then it may be hard - I don't know.)

Here's the LINQ query though:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesFromNamespace(Assembly assembly, 
                                               String desiredNamespace)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes()
                   .Where(type => type.Namespace == desiredNamespace);
}
```