# How can I get all classes within a namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, namespaces

How can I get all classes within a namespace in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taking out all classes of a specific namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343869/taking-out-all-classes-of-a-specific-namespace)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all types in a namespace via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You will need to do it "backwards"; list all the types in an assembly and then checking the namespace of each type:

```
using System.Reflection;
private Type[] GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
{
    return 
      assembly.GetTypes()
              .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal))
              .ToArray();
}
```

Example of usage:

```
Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "MyNamespace");
for (int i = 0; i < typelist.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typelist[i].Name);
}
```

---

For anything before .Net 2.0 where `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` is not available, you will need a small workaround to get the assembly:

```
Assembly myAssembly = typeof(<Namespace>.<someClass>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace(myAssembly, "<Namespace>");
for (int i = 0; i < typelist.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typelist[i].Name);
}
```

Comment: .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Assembly != namespace - some namespaces are spread across multiple assemblies.

Comment: and why not to return just a IEnumerable<Type>? All the more, you do an enumeration between the results, also 'foreach' instead of 'for' is better, I think.

Comment: Good comments, thanks for that. By making the return type to an IEnumerable<Type> eliminates the need for the last ToArray call. Not sure if I agree that 'foreach' is better than 'for' though; as I see it the performance difference is neglectible so I think it comes down to personal style. But may have a good argument for preferring 'foreach'; if so feel free to share it; I like to be proven wrong :)

Comment: I think foreach is just easier to look at personally. Behind the scenes the two loops are pretty much the same in regards to performance.

Comment: @Chev I agree, I would have used `IEnumerable` and `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to provide a little more information...

Do you mean by using Reflection. You can iterate through an assemblies Manifest
and get a list of types using

```
   System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("");

   myAssembly.ManifestModule.FindTypes()
```

If it's just in Visual Studio, you can just get the list in the intellisense window, or by opening the Object Browser (CTRL+W, J)

Answer (score 0):

With Reflection you cal loop through all the types in an assembly. A type has a Namespace property which you use to filter only the namespace you're interested in.