# Get list of classes in namespace in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to programmatically get a `List` of all the classes in a given namespace. How can I achieve this (reflection?) in C#?

Comment: How annoying when a question gets marked as a duplicate and the original is not referenced.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
var theList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                      .Where(t => t.Namespace == "your.name.space")
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: There's always the "one-liners". ;-)

Comment: Yeah, you gotta love a one-liner :-)

Comment: This assumes the whole namespace is in the current assembly, A partial solution at best.

Comment: War, what would be a better solution then?

Answer (score 5):

Without LINQ:

Try:

```
Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
List<Type> myTypes = new List<Type>();
foreach (Type t in types)
{
  if (t.Namespace=="My.Fancy.Namespace")
    myTypes.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().ToList() will give you the list you want.

Comment: Yes Greg, though technically, that is using a LINQ extension method and my example was meant to show this without having .NET 3.5

Comment: clean non linq example though OP doesn't say that the assembly has already been loaded so the code might return an empty set eventhough the list should have been long and a name space might be in more assemblies :)

Comment: Fair point, I should have just created a method with an Assembly parameter as input and left the client call up to the OP altogether. ;-)

Comment: Same namespaces in more assemblies is not how I would design it. Fine for base namespaces, but I definitely wouldn't have types in the same namespaces spread out over multiple assemblies. That's nasty.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [How to get all classes within namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-to-get-all-classes-within-namespace) the answer provided returns an array of Type[] you can modify this easily to return List

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of looping through types in an assebly to find ones iin the correct namespace

```
public List<Type> GetList()
        {
            List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            foreach (var type in assembly .GetTypes())
            {
                if (type.Namespace == "Namespace")
                {
                    types.Add(type);
                }
            }
            return types;
        }
```