# C# Get a List of Classes in a Namespace per Reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, system.reflection

I want to use Reflection to fill my Checkboxes dynamically.

I found an helping answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835665/get-list-of-classes-in-namespace-in-c-sharp)

And used it in my Code:

```
    public static List<System.Type> getModuleList()
    {
        // fill with all Classes in Timestamp.View.UserControls.ModuleView per Reflection


        List<System.Type> theList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                              .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Timestamp.View.UserControls.ModuleView")
                              .ToList();


        return theList;
    }
```

I filled my Checkboxes like:

```
   foreach (System.Type type in ModuleController.getModuleList())
        {
            cbModule1.Items.Add(type);
            cbModule2.Items.Add(type);
            cbModule3.Items.Add(type);
            cbModule4.Items.Add(type);
        }
```

1. Now i want to create a new Instance of the SelectedType

   ```
     private void CbModule4_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       ucModul4.Content = //new Instance of Selected Item
   }
   ```

I could use Reflection to create a new Instance, but I dont know how.

2. I want to give every Class a String which will be shown as Item in the Checkbox. Is this possible, or do I need a Method to find a Class by its String?

EDIT: I need to argue why my question differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type)

So first of all this question could only solve one of my Problems, but i found it earlier and it didn't helped me. I don't know how to get the type of the list and how i can give the class an alias.

Comment: Don't go for reflection over namespaces, define a shared interface as they all seem to have something in common, and then just get the types that implement this interface. Then you can fill those properties you want in a typed way, and presumably they would have a label and a checked property

Comment: @Icepickle They all have a shared Interface called IModuleView. But how do i get all Classes implementing this Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because adding `Type` to combobox makes `type.ToString()` and puts string representation into `combobox`, you can use

`var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(cbModule4.SelectedText))`

When passing type, you can do:

`var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(theList[0]))`

Comment: I cant override type.ToString() right?

Comment: you can make helper class like ComboItem and and instances of it into combobox

Comment: Nice Idea, thank you :)

Comment: @itskajo Do you need an example?

Comment: Nah thank you :) I wrote a little Class doing this :)

Comment: @itskajo well, then you can mark this question as solved and my reply as solution :)