# filtering of dll with certain conditions

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have bunch of dll written with C# and I know the namespace name used in it. i just need to get list of dll which uses  sqlconnection.open() method  or used namespace system.data.sqlclient in it.Is there some way to do it programmatically with C#?

Comment: Try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-to-get-all-classes-within-namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var methodsCallingDbConnectionOpen = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location)
            .MainModule
            .GetTypes()
            .SelectMany(type => type.Methods)
            .Where(method => method.HasBody &&
                method.Body.Instructions.Any(instruction =>
                    instruction.OpCode.Code == Code.Callvirt && instruction.Operand is MethodReference &&
                    ((MethodReference)instruction.Operand).FullName.Contains("System.Data.Common.DbConnection::Open")));

        foreach (var method in methodsCallingDbConnectionOpen)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(method);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Foo()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

> System.Void ConsoleApplication1.Program::Foo()

Notes:

- This sample uses [`Mono.Cecil`](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).
- This sample detects call to `DbConnection.Open`. To detect which descendant of DbConnection being used, you have to look into previous IL instructions (e.g., ctor call).

Comment: i am getting a error as 'Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition' does not contain a definition for 'ReadAssembly'

Comment: can u say me which version of mono did u use it

Comment: @GowthamanSS, I've added reference to Cecil through NuGet, without downloading Mono: https://nuget.org/packages/Mono.Cecil/0.9.5.3. If you're using VS prior to 2010, you can download Cecil from its Github page: https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/

Comment: i have just replaced "System.Data.Common.DbConnection::Open" to "System.IO.File::Create" in order to find out method that uses create method but it throw me an error can u guide me

Comment: i do not get any exception it does not read the method name which having file.create() method inside it

Comment: what i did is i have change the "System.Data.Common.DbConnection::Open" to "System.IO.File::Create" and the below class as static void Foo()
    {
        File.Create("s.txt");
    }
i do not know whether is correct

Comment: @GowthamanSS: this is because of `OpCode.Code` - `File.Create` is a static method, so it is called via `call` (Code.Call). I would recommend you to read something more about call/callvirt IL instructions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15170/discussion-between-gowthamanss-and-dennis)