# Dictionary of class instances

Tags: c#

I want to have a dictionary of class instances like this:

```
Dictionary<string, class> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, class>();

// Load all classes of a namespace
Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "GameStates");
for (int i = 0; i < typelist.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typelist[i].Name);
    gameStateList.Add(typelist[i].Name, typelist[i]);
}

dictionary["ClassA"].MethodB(5); // Doesn't work
```

How could I do that?

Comment: This is currently invalid code - `class` is a keyword. And you're not creating any instances at all.

Comment: I know, that was an example as I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Well if you're saying something "doesn't work" that suggests the code before it is valid - in this case, it isn't.

Comment: See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/mapping-from-a-type-to-an-instance-of-that-type.aspx for a blog post about this though.

Comment: Can you provide more informations on what you want to accomplish? Perhaps there's a better and easier way to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that there are two different things in C#. A *class specification*, which describes a class, is contained in a `Type` object. A *class instance*, which describes a particular object, is an `object` or any derived class.

There are some additional issues with your code, but I think you can solve them yourself once you get how types and instances work.

---

In this case, [`GetTypesInNamespace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949285/146622) returns a list of `Type` objects, thus class specifications. You can put them in a dictionary if you want.

```
Dictionary<string, Type> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
```

Then, if you want to make the class specification into an instance, you have to call the class constructor. You can use reflection on the `Type` for that.

```
// Get the type.
Type someType = dictionary["ClassA"];

// Create an instance.
object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(someType);
```

Note that the above example works for classes that have a default parameterless constructor. If your classes have constructors with parameters, look at the [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method's documentation to find out how to pass those parameters.

---

Now you want to call `MethodB` on the instance. There are three ways to do this.

1. You know the type of the instance, and you cast the instance to the correct type.

   ```
   ClassA myClassA = (ClassA)myInstance;
   myClassA.MethodB(5);
   ```
2. You don't know the type of the instance, but you know it has a method `MethodB`, and you're using .NET 4 or newer.

   ```
   dynamic myDynamicInstance = (dynamic)myInstance;
   myInstance.MethodB(5);
   ```

   When the instance' class doesn't have a `MethodB`, you'll get an exception.
3. Using reflection. This is a bit more complicated. Search around if you need it. I think `dynamic` is the way to go for you here.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are talking about class *instances*, the best you can do without knowing anything else is a dictionary of objects:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict;
```

But this is not going to be useful at all since you want to call methods on them. It is better to have your states implement a certain interface so that you can call the appropriate method:

```
Dictionary<string, IGameState> dict;
```

You can then fill this dictionary just like Virtlink explained in his nice answer.