# List all the class names from single cs file

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I need all the class names to be listed out from .cs file i tried to Google it but couldn't figure it out. Please help me to get the list.

I have code like this:

```
public partial class example1 : BaseEntity
{
}

public partial class example2 : BaseEntity
{
}
```

Comment: Depending what you're trying to do, you could use the Roslyn API to get that information.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exacly what you are trying to achieve. But if you put all your classes in a namespace you maybe can retrive them from that. Here is another discussion in that topic:
[How to get all classes within namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-to-get-all-classes-within-namespace)