# Getting the right class by attribute based on string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public ActionResult AddComplianceForm(string TemplateName)
{
}
```

In this ASP.net MVC5 application there is a folder Templates that contains a bunch of different classes that all have different TemplateName attributes.  The first part of this method needs to find the class that has a TemplateName matching the string passed in.  I then need to create an instance of whatever template matched.  I am very new to working with attributes in C# so help would be very appreciated.  I mostly need to know how to access that folder of classes in the program to look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called "Reflection" in C#.

Below is the link to another answer that shows how to get all the classes in a namespace (I'm assuming that the physical folder implies the use of a unique namespace for the classes contained in the folder.)

[Link to StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-to-get-all-classes-within-namespace)

**Btw you should look up reflection performance and see if it makes sense in your case. You may want to use a factory pattern instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult AddComplianceForm(string TemplateName)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Testy20161006");                     //assembly name
        Type t = assembly.GetType("Testy20161006.Templates." + TemplateName);   //namespace + class name
        Object obj = (Object)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't just use reflection**

The typical way someone would deal with this is with Reflection and run-time type discovery/binding. However, this is probably a poor starting point in this exact situation. The template name is passed in as an action argument, presumably through binding to a value in the request string, and you don't want c# code that will instantiate whatever class is passed in from the web!!! That would be a serious security issue known as an [insecure direct object reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).

**Create a list**

To mitigate the risk, the proper approach is to check the argument against a [whitelist](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet#Whitelisting_vs_blacklisting).  Well, if we have a white list already, we may as well associate each item in the list with a lambda expression that returns the object you want.

```
class MyController
{
    static private readonly Dictionary<string,Func<BaseTemplate>> _templateList = new Dictionary<string,Func<BaseTemplate>>();

    static MyController() 
    {
        _templateList.Add("ATemplate",         () => return new ATemplate());
        _templateList.Add("SomeOtherTemplate", () => return new SomeOtherTemplate());
        _templateList.Add("JustOneMore",       () => return new JustOneMore());
    }

    public ActionResult AddComplianceForm(string TemplateName)
    {
        BaseTemplate template;
        try
        {
            template = _templateList[TemplateName]();
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException exception)
        {
            RedirectToAction("MyController", "InvalidTemplateError");
        }

        DoSomethingWithTemplate(template);
    }

}
```

**Create the list using Reflection**

But what if you have a crap ton of templates?  You don't want to hard code all those dictionary entries, right?

Well, you could tag each of the templates with a custom attribute, e.g. `[TemplateAttribute]`, and then populate the list this way:

```
        foreach (Assembly b in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (Type t in b.GetTypes())
            {
                var a = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(TemplateAttribute));
                if (a != null)
                {
                    var localType = t; //Avoid closure on loop variable
                    _templateList.Add(t.Name, () => Activator.CreateInstance(localType) as BaseTemplate);
                }
            }
        }
```

This will automatically iterate through all the types that are loaded for your application and find the ones with the `TemplateAttribute`. Only those types will be allowed in the action argument.

Notes:

In these examples I assume all of your templates inherit from a `BaseTemplate`, but if they have no ancestor in common (not recommended) I guess you could just use `object`.

In these examples, I store the list and implement the code in the controller, but if you are going for well-structured code you should consider moving all that stuff into some sort of factory class and just pass the string in from the controller.