# Is there a way to get all Function (or Sub) names from a specific namespace in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I found the following code regarding to a class:

```
    Dim NetBook As New Book("AAA","BBB", 49.99)

    Console.WriteLine("Method Names")
    Dim Info As Reflection.MethodInfo

    For Each Info In NetBook.GetType.GetMethods()
        Console.WriteLine(Info.Name)
    Next
```

Is that possible regarding to a namespace (or, still better than class, a module)?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get all classes within a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-can-i-get-all-classes-within-a-namespace)

Comment: I'm using a class now. Thank you.