# How to reflect/map models received from frontend into models at backend?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, mediatr

I want to make universal `JSON` generator for any `ViewModel` received from frontend. I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-7.0) that I can get type from string, but I do not know how to implement this in my case.
My idea was to send from Angular array with 2 values, first would be string that say what type is my `ViewModel`, and second value would be `ViewModel`, which I need to convert to `JSON`. (I need this `JSON`on backend for converting to other file formats, and I have some special requirements, like change of name property, etc.)
I am using `MediatR`, and here are my classes:
`GenerateJSONQuery` is input object, the one I will get from frontend.

```
 public class GenerateJSONQuery<T> : IRequest<string>
    {
      public string TypeOfList { get; set; }
      public List<T> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

`GenerateJSONQueryHandler` is `MediatR` handler that will do reflection to `ViewModel` and generate `JSON`.

```
public class GenerateJSONQueryHandler<T> : IRequestHandler<GenerateJSONQuery<T>, string>
    {
        private readonly IddeeaODPDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
       

        public GenerateJSONQueryHandler(IddeeaODPDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<string> Handle(GenerateJSONQuery<T> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
           // logic for generating files, in this part I need to somehow convert 
           // `request.Data` to specific List<T> where
           //  T can be e.g. `NewbornByBirthDateViewModel`, 
           //`IssuedDocumentsViewModel`, `RegisteredVehiclesViewModel`, etc. etc.
        }
```

Controller that connect `IRequest` and `IRequestHandler` is:

```
public class GenerateFilesController : ApiBaseController
    {
        public GenerateFilesController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings) : base(appSettings)
        {

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Administration/Document" })]
        public async Task<string> List<T>([FromBody] GenerateJSONQuery<T> data, [FromHeader] string Authorization)
        {
            return await Mediator.Send(data);
            
        }

    }
```

and `NewbornByBirthDateViewModel` is example `VieWModel` that I need to serialize into `JSON`.

```
public class ClientNewbornByBirthDateViewModel 
    {
    
       [TranslatedFieldName("Identifier", LanguageEnum.EN)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Institution { get; set; }
       [TranslatedFieldName("Men", LanguageEnum.EN)]
        public int MaleTotal { get; set; }
       [TranslatedFieldName("Women", LanguageEnum.EN)]
        public int FemaleTotal { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
   }
```

I am pretty sure that my thinking way is bad, and that I need to do some kind of reflection, but I do not know how. I can not send only type of `ViewModel` from frontend, and then select all from `db` with `context.Set<T>()` because there can be filters, and those filters depends on which `ViewModel` is selected, so  I must pass object with data from frontend to `JSONGenerate` logic and then reflect it to specific `ViewModel` on backend.

Answer (score 0):

Your application must first understand classes and their types before attempting to use reflection by passing the data type name as a parameter.

> For that get all the data types using reflection on which you want to
> reflect your data on then filter out by using
> **TypeOfList**.

Use this link to get all classes details within a namespace.
[How can I get all classes within a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-can-i-get-all-classes-within-a-namespace)