# Get System.Type from another assembly in the generator code of a T4 text template

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, t4

I'm writing a T4 text template which reads a CSV containing class names with their full namespace (MyNamespace.ClassExample) which are in an assembly different to where the T4 resides.

I need to resolve the correspondent `System.Type` in the generator code of the T4.

I've already tried resolving a type from `System` and it works just as expected, but when I try to resolve a type from my assembly it returns null. Even using the full asembly name.

```cs
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)ClassLibrary1.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="ClassLibrary1" #>
<#
    Type type = Type.GetType("System.String");
    Type type2 = Type.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1");
    Type type3 = Type.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1, ClassLibrary1");
#>
This is a <#=type#>
This is a <#=type2#>
This is a <#=type3#>
```

Produces the following output:

```
This is a System.String
This is a null
This is a null
```

As you can see, I've tried to load the assembly dll, include the `ClassLibrary1` namespace just in case (even if it shouldn't be needed).

Also tried using EnvDTE, this answer to a similar question looked promising https://stackoverflow.com/a/38225980/2347708 but it can't resolve `ITypeResolutionService`

```cs
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDte" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)ClassLibrary1.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="ClassLibrary1" #>
<#
    Type GetTypeByName(IServiceProvider provider, string typeName)
    {
        var svc = (ITypeResolutionService)provider.GetService(typeof(ITypeResolutionService));
        // svc is null.
        return svc.GetType(typeName);
    }

    Type type = Type.GetType("System.String");
    Type type2 = GetTypeByName((IServiceProvider)this.Host, "ClassLibrary1.Class1, ClassLibrary1");
#>
This is a <#=type#>
This is a <#=type2#>
```

Comment: Have you actually build the other project with the fully processed template?

Comment: Expanding on the previous answer, with a simple extension you can trigger processing templates before build, and process after, if this is a solution. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TimMaes.ttexecuter