# Loop through all classes in a given namespace and create an object for each?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to loop through each class in a namespace and initialize an object for each class?

For instance, I want to loop through all classes in the Test.POS namespace, create an object for each class, and call the `runImportProcess` method on each object.

I know that I can loop through a namespace like so:

```
Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), 
                                      "Test.POS");

foreach (Type t in typelist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to use this `t` variable to accomplish what I want.  Any insight for a novice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Assembly.GetTypes()`. Then filter them by the namespace (and ensure they are what you want). To instantiate them, use `Activator.CreateInstance(...)`.

Comment: Perfect!  Now, the real challenge is to call the `runImportProcess()` method on this new object.  Since the compiler isn't aware of the class' properties and methods at compile time, is this even possible?  Looking at this example, it seems like I have to programmatically define which type the variable would be after I call `Activator.CreateInstance()` - `ObjectType instance = (ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);`

Comment: you can do that - even better - create a shared interface.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var types = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Namespace.StartsWith("Test.POS"));

foreach (var t in types)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GetConstructor` method

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Addition
{
    public Addition(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor called, a={0}", a);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Type type = typeof(Addition);
        ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });
        object instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { 10 });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflector to get all the classes from an assembly:

[Getting all types in a namespace via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection)

and then use activator to create new instances of the retrieved classes:

[Get a new object instance from a Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type)