# Automating an object repository for a game

Tags: c#

Hello guys i am having trouble designing an object repository for a game:

```
class ObjectRepository
{

private readonly LevelType _levelType;

private readonly BaseObject[] _darkForestObjects = new BaseObject[] 
                { new DarkForestTreeA(), new DarkForestTreeB(), new DarkForestTreeC() };

private readonly BaseObject[] _lightForestObjects = new BaseObject[] 
                { new LightForestTreeA(), new LightForestTreeB(), new LightForestTreeC() };

public ObjectRepository(LevelType lt)
{
    _levelType = lt;
}

public BaseObject GetObject(int obj)
{
    if (obj < 0 || obj > _darkForestObjects.Length)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Object does not exist.");
        return null;
    }

    switch (_levelType)
    {
        case LevelType.DarkForest:
           return _darkForestObjects[obj];
        case LevelType.LightForest:
           return _lightForestObjects[obj];
    }

    return null;
}
}

public enum LevelType
{
    DarkForest = 0,
    LightForest = 1,
}
```

I am searching for a way of automating this class.By automating it i mean that i don't want every time i create a new object deriving from BaseObject to come inside the Repository class and modify arrays.It just doesn't seem natural.Can anybody point me out a suggestion for automation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You want to automate your respository, but "automate the repository" _doesn't_ mean automatically including new `BaseObject` instances in the repository's collection? What is it that you're trying to automate, then?

Comment: I must confess I had the same issue as @BrianS. If possible, I'd ask you to be *less* code-specific, and describe what you actually want to do. Let me try anyway: Do you want to, whenever a new BaseObject-derived object is created, to automatically add it to your repository collection? Also, you think that array manipulation can be somewhat clunky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a gander at this, so please let me know if I'm assuming things wrong.

You'll need:

- A repository that'll hold your BaseObject-derived instances;
- Said repository must be accessible by the BaseObject class;
- Whenever a BaseObject is created, it adds itself to the repository.

Now, I've noticed that you hold instances for both *dark* and *light* versions of your objects. So I'd additionally suggest a holder class for both light and dark versions of a given 'object'. Like this:

```
class CompoundObject
{
    public BaseObject LightVersion;
    public BaseObject DarkVersion;
}
```

Your repository then hold `CompoundObject`-derived objects, and instead of `BaseObject` objects adding themselves at creation time, `CompoundObject` objects would do it.

Now about Array manipulations, you may be right; it can be somewhat clunky. I'd suggest the adoption of `List<CompoundObject>` instead of `CompoundObject[]`. A generic [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) offer very handy methods like Add and Remove that can streamline your collection manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would opt for a more generic solution using interfaces.
Considering your example, I assume that you have multiple level types which have their own specific TreeA, TreeB and TreeC implementations.
If I understood right, I would rather use interface for each tree type. Example for TreeA :

```
public interface ITreeA
{
  // any common public members here
}

public class DarkForestTreeA : ITreeA, BaseObject
{
    ...
}

public class LightForestTreeA : ITreeA, BaseObject
{
    ...
}
```

This way, you can ask your repository to provide the ITreeA implementation specific to the level type. Something like :

```
public T GetObject<T>() // where T could be ITreeA, ITreeB...
{
    ...
}
```

So you could call myRepo.GetObject() and get a DarkForestTreeA object if level type is DarkForest for example.

To have this behavior "automated", you could declare all the specific implementations of DarkForest in a unique namespace and then use reflexion to find the class of the namespace that implements ITreeA for example. This may not be very efficient in terms of performance but it gives you great flexibility as you will just have to add new classes in your namespace to have them available from the repository. However, it can also bring other problems (for example, what would happen if you have two classes implementing ITreeA in the same namespace ?).
See [Getting all types in a namespace via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection) and [Getting all types that implement an interface with C# 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface-with-c-sharp-3-0) for implementation details.

I have to admit it isn't the simplest solution.

You could consider simpler thing like defining a dictionary for object type (treeA, treeB) and then define a dictionary for each level type mapping the object type to its concrete implementation.
For example :

```
public enum ObjectType
{
    TreeA,
    TreeB,
    TreeC,
}

Dictionary<ObjectType, Type> DarkForestObjectTypes = new Dictionary<ObjectType, Type>()
{
    { ObjectType.TreeA, typeof(DarkForestTreeA) },
    { ObjectType.TreeB, typeof(DarkForestTreeB) }
    ...
}
```

I won't go into more details as this answer looks a bit messy but hopefully it will give you ideas to go on with.

Comment: +1 - Interfaces would indeed be a nice approach as well.