# get Classes and Methods from another Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I Have a Solution with 2 Proyects:

- __mvc4
- getClassesMethods

the getClassesMethods have a reference to __mvc4 , so I want to get All the Classes and Methods from a namespace inside the __mvc4 Project so I have this code to Load and get all the Assemblies from the AppDomain

Here's is the breakpoint at the var asssemblies (contains the __mvc4 Assembly)

[image]

```
    namespace getClassesMethods
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {


                var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
                var loadedPaths = loadedAssemblies.Select(a => a.Location).ToArray();

                var referencedPaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll");
                var toLoad = referencedPaths.Where(r => !loadedPaths.Contains(r, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
                toLoad.ForEach(path => loadedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path))));

                var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
```

But I don't know how to get all the Classes and Methods from the ___mvc4 Assembly in the var assemblies. Hope you can help me!

Comment: What are you trying to do that reflecting the assembly is the solution? This awfully looks like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), could you explain what your end goal that getting all of the classes and methods would help you solve?

Comment: "classes" in C# are called "Types" in .Net - so method you are looking is [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Fortunately for methods C# and  .Net agree on name - `GetMethods` of each type.

Comment: sounds as it was answered before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection

Comment: My end goal is to get all the Methods from all the classes that are in another project in the same solution @ScottChamberlain

Comment: the link was really helpful , thanks @T.S.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a sample

```
foreach(var asm in loadedAssemblies)
{
   var classes = asm.GetTypes(); // you can use GetTypes to get all classes in that assembly
   foreach(var c in classes)
   {
      // you can get all methods which is defined in this class with GetMethods
      var methods = c.GetMethods();

      // or you can get all properties defined in this class
      var props = c.GetProperties();
   }
}
```

For more information see [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and read this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(asm=>asm.GetTypes());
var methods = types.SelectMany(type=>type.GetMethods());
```

**NOTE**

"classes" are called "types" in .NET.