# Get all .net available type in system namespace

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Is there a function or by using reflection a way to get all the System types.

Like those:
- `System.Int64`

- `System.Byte[]`
- `System.Boolean`
- `System.String`
- `System.Decimal`
- `System.Double`
- ...

We have an old `enum` that stores some datatype. We need to convert those to .net `types`.

Comment: A similar entry answering your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you only want types from `mscorlib`, it's easy:

```
var mscorlib = typeof(string).Assembly;
var types = mscorlib.GetTypes()
                    .Where(t => t.Namespace == "System");
```

However, that *won't* return `byte[]`, as that's an array type. It also won't return types in different assemblies. If you have multiple assemblies you're interested in, you could use:

```
var assemblies = ...;
var types = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                      .Where(t => t.Namespace == "System");
```

Comment: This returns more than what I wants. Is there a way to get only the basic once like. In fact, I'm doing a mapping between the database type and the  .net types. So I need to convert an old sql column in the database by replacing the it with a .net type.

Comment: @billybob: Well then you should have specified exactly what you wanted. I've answered the question you asked: "Get all .net available type in system namespace" - it's really not at all clear what you really want, but it sounds like it's *not* what you actually asked for...

Comment: Thanks. I think i will just hard code the ones that I need to map with the .net type. It answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

@jon-skeet: Thanks a lot for your great solution!

If some complete noob (like me) reads this topic, I found a tiny tweak for Jon Skeet's code to get more specified output. For example:

```
        Assembly mscorlib = typeof(int).Assembly; 
        IEnumerable<System.Type> types = mscorlib.GetTypes()
                            .Where(t => t.Namespace == "System" && t.IsPrimitive);
```

The second argument "...&& t.{here_is_property}" in the last codeline is one of Type Class properties. You can try another one from [.NET official reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netstandard-2.0#properties) to get what you exactly need.