# How to get all namespace in project by assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces

I want get all namespace in main project by method assembly.(Not all aseembly)

I read below question but not useful.

> [Getting all types in a namespace via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection/79738#79738)

for example

class in Assembly:

```
namespace test
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string[] AllNameSpace()
        {
            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Select(x => x.Namespace).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

code in main project:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var util=new Class1();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",util.AllNameSpace()));//return test
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

return "test" But I want contain ConsoleApplication1 namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly` instead of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` and you should get the `ConsoleApplication1`-Assembly.

You get all Namespaces of that Assembly, but it will sure contain `ConsoleApplication1`, but not only.

Comment: @patrickEchebrecht Thank you for your answer. but not answer in Asp.Net MVC . return Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods . Can you help me?

Comment: No Sorry :-/ Ask a new question with the ASP.NET tag. Sure someone will be able to help.