# List of all controllers in an Area?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do i programmatically find list of all the controllers in a particular area ?

I did a Google search, but was not able to find anything relevant to it.

Since all the Controller to a particular area lies in a fixed `namespace`, i am thinking to find all `controller` that belongs in that `namespace` using reflection. Is there any other possible way ?

Comment: `find all controller that belongs in that namespace using reflection`, i think that should work.

Answer (score 1):

See [Getting all types in a namespace via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection)

Can add a statement to that inner query like so...

```
string @namespace = "MyApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers";
var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace 
        && typeof(t).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller))
        select t;
```