# How can I search the assemblies for all the classes available in a specific namespace with from a controller using c#?

Tags: c#

I need to get all available classes in a giving namespace.

Here is what I have done

In my `Index` method in `XyzController.cs` I added this line.

```
var classesList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace == "PATH.TO.HAMESPACE").ToList()
```

Unfortunately, that gave me no records/classes.

However, when I created a new class in the the same namespace i.e. `PATH.TO.HAMESPACE`. with the same code. Then called this class from the controller, the code returns the correct classes list.

How can I run this code from the controller to get all available classes with in `PATH.TO.HAMESPACE`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all types in a namespace via reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection)

Comment: I think the problem is that your assembly is not loaded at the time you are trying to get the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overkill method, but that could work:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Namespace");
```

Or (and), you should try to load explicitly your assembly.
With [Assembly.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) or [Assembly.LoadFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx).

```
Assembly.Load("your assembly fullname")
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Namespace");
```

Comment: The firs method you provided worked. How can I determine the full qualifying name for my assembly?

Comment: To get the assembly fullname, you can do that: `Type t = yourType` and copy this string: `t.Assembly.FullName`. If you reference the project in your csproj, you can find it in the project xml too.

Comment: Since you are able to get your types with my first method, instead of loading you could try the @TarekAboElkheir's method, that should work too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of GetExecutingAssembly() try GetAssembly(typeof(PATH.TO.HAMESPACE.SampleClass))

The problem is when you are in the controller the executing Assembly in not the same assembly of the classes you need, while when you  created that class , the assemble is the correct one.

So you need to get the correct assembly and then filter it