# Get methods and attributes from dll assembly

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm trying to get a small plugin mechanism running by reflecting an dll file providing my class `Plugin` (implementing my `Plugin`-Interface shared among dll and main project / sorry for naming both the same) offering an attribute of type `string` and a main-method `activate`:

Interface:

```
public interface Plugin
{
    string pluginName{get;set;}
    void activate(System.Windows.Forms.Form main);
}
```

dll class:

```
    public class Plugin : WhiteA.Plugin
        {
            public string pluginName{get;set;}

            public void activate(System.Windows.Forms.Form main){
                //find the right form to modify it
                IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox> ie= GetControlsOfType<System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox>(main);
                System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cb=GetControlsOfType<System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox>(main).FirstOrDefault();
                cb.Items.Add("Modification");
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(cb.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }

            public static IEnumerable<T> GetControlsOfType<T>(System.Windows.Forms.Control root)
                where T : System.Windows.Forms.Control
            {
                var t = root as T;
                if (t != null)
                    yield return t;

                var container = root as System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl;
                if (container != null)
                    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control c in container.Controls)
                        foreach (var i in GetControlsOfType<T>(c))
                            yield return i;
            }
        }
```

So here comes the problem, there is no `type` named `"Plugin"` to be found in the assembly. Tried to get all types from all assemblies in the directory, get all methods/members/custom attributes from them, have them logged etc, but there is nothing of my class `Plugin` to be found, while the dll definitely is being found, as it doesn't return the `MessageBox`.

```
string[] files=new string[]{};
            string path="Error retrieving path";
            try{
                path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll");
            }catch(Exception exF){

            }
            if(files.Length>0){
                foreach (string dll in files){
                    try{
                        System.Reflection.Assembly sampleAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(dll);
                        Type myType = sampleAssembly.GetType("Plugin");
                        System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = myType.GetMethod("activate");
                        object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
                        method.Invoke(myInstance, new object[]{this});
                    }catch(Exception exL){

                    }
                }
            }else{
                MessageBox.Show("No working plugins detected in " + path.ToString(), "Nothing to activate", MessageBoxButtons.OK,  MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
```

I know my code probably looks really messy to you all - I think the last `try`-block is the only thing relevant here, wanted to put in the class itself and the interface for a little bit transparency though - and my english isn't perfect, but I hope someone can help me out finding my attribute+method in the assembly.

**EDIT**:

```
                    try{
                        System.Reflection.Assembly sampleAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(dll);

                        List<Type> list= sampleAssembly.GetTypes().Where(p =>
                                             p.Namespace == dll &&
                                             p.Name.Contains("Plugin")
                                            ).ToList();
                        Type myType=list.FirstOrDefault();

                        //Type myType = sampleAssembly.GetType("Plugin");
                        System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = myType.GetMethod("activate");
                        object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
                        method.Invoke(myInstance, new object[]{this});

                    }
```

I did change it according to [Getting all types in a namespace via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection/34869091#34869091) 
Still the same result, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I think you need to pass the namespace to `GetType()`? like for example `sampleAssembly.GetType("MyApp.Plugins.Plugin");`? Note that you shouln't pass the _assembly_ name - see [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This has been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection/34869091#34869091

Comment: @stuartd that would mean all my plugins need to have the same namespace, right? Is that necessary/allowed?

Comment: As long as they're all in different assemblies, then it's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As pointed out by @stuartd*:

```
Type myType = sampleAssembly.GetType("WhiteA_Plugin_PausedVideo.Plugin");
```

is the solution, **missed the namespace**

```
cb.Items.Add("Modification");
```

doesn't work though...any suggestions?

Got it to work **getting the form's children by Controls["nameOfChild"] directly**, that help method to fetch all objects by class seems to be wrong here.

*Plugin works now, thanks!*