# Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'Type'

Tags: c#, .net, api, reflection, .net-core

I'm trying to register automatically the classes for Dependency Injection in a loop instead of manually. However the method I'm using is not compiling.

Method that is working:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyClass>();
```

Method that doesn't compile:

```
List<Type> servicesList = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "MyNamespace.Services").Where(type => type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsGenericType && !type.IsNested).ToList<Type>();
for (int i = 0; i < servicesList.Count; i++)
{
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<servicesList[i]>();
}
```

The compiler throws this error message:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'Type'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79706/3583859 this might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using generic arguments incorrectly.

You can register by type

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType(servicesList[i]);
```

Reference [Reflection Components: Register by Type](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#register-by-type)