# Xamarin - Insert into multiple SQLite tables at once?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have a Xamarin app with multiple tables of data that it pulls from an API. At the moment, the code that calls the API and inserts the data looks like this:

```
try
            {
                // Table1
                var table1Response = await httpClient.Value.GetStringAsync("http://website.com/api/table1");
                var table1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Table1>>(table1Response);
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
                {
                    conn.CreateTable<Table1>();
                    conn.DeleteAll<Table1>();
                    conn.InsertAll(table1);
                    conn.Close();
                }

                // Table2
                var table2Response = await httpClient.Value.GetStringAsync("http://website.com/api/table2");
                var table2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Table2>>(table2Response);
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
                {
                    // Checks for table and creates if doesn't exist
                    conn.CreateTable<Table2>();
                    // Deletes all old data
                    conn.DeleteAll<Table2>();
                    // Updates with new reference data from API
                    conn.InsertAll(table2);
                    conn.Close();
                }
// Repeats for all tables in the app.
```

Because it has to await the API call, when this method is called in the app's OnStart() the data loads in table by table, and if you navigate to a page in the app that requires certain data that hasn't finished being called yet, obviously the app crashes. I asked yesterday for help with a function I was writing to insert the data programmatically using a foreach loop (see: [Xamarin/C# - Insert data into SQLite database programmatically for multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58387768/xamarin-c-insert-data-into-sqlite-database-programmatically-for-multiple-tabl)) and I was informed that that's not a smart way to do it and defining each table as you need it is a better method.

My question now becomes, what can I do to my API calling method to have it make multiple API calls at once and hypothetically load all the data in one shot? Is this even possible to do, or should I try building a Loading screen of sorts that waits until all the data has been retrieved before allowing further use of the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `backgrounding Service` in xamarin form.

> Background Services are very commonly used for tasks that are
>   performed in the background, such as downloading files, long
>   calculations, playing music, and periodic method call. Each platform
>   has a different way on enabling and registering the Background
>   Service.

Because each platform has their own way and rules for background services. We have to make services for each platform.

For more details, you can  check:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1YzyreS4-o

https://robgibbens.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/

https://winstongubantes.blogspot.com/2018/09/backgrounding-with-xamarinforms-easy-way.html

Besides, if you want to dig deeper about advance Background Service per each platform you can check on this links below:

Android BackgroundServices [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/)

iOS BackgroundServices [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/introduction-to-backgrounding-in-ios)